# Do apps still need to support iPhone 3GS?

Tags: iphone, iphone-3gs, retina

Are new iPhone apps still required to support the old iPhone 3GS and other non-retina devices? I'm wondering because I already have a full set of retina graphics and I want to submit the app without having to create a set of non-retina graphics.

Comment: I'm still using a 3GS... Works perfectly on 6.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a matter of personal preference. Apple Inc. says that you must support the retina display but there is nothing that prevents you from supporting the lower versions of the iPhone. If you want to reach those who still use older iDevices, you can. But there are not many left out there. It is up to you, though. I believe you have a wide audience using devices that use retina display, but using a lower target deployment is not a bad idea for increasing the sales of your application.

Answer (score 0):

[iOS 7 isn't going to run on a 3GS](http://www.tuaw.com/2013/06/10/ios-7-phases-out-the-iphone-3gs-and-the-original-ipad-some-feat/), so if you want to run on iOS 7 ***only***, then you don't have to worry about it.